# 400 Client Error: Bad Request using python-social-auth for Facebook auth in Django

Tags: django, facebook, facebook-oauth, python-social-auth

Lately some strange errors have happened in a project I'm working on. It was working perfectly fine when one day (without any changes on our side that I know of) Facebook authentication with python-social-auth for django stopped working. The error given was "400 Client Error: Bad Request" and seemingly occurred in the /complete/facebook callback.

I have tried switching to older code, creating a new Facebook app from scratch and switching the settings of the existing one, all to no avail.

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this? Help would be greatly appreaciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked this bug report: https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/190 ?

Comment: It seems that was the issue! There was a problem in one of the elements of the social auth pipeline and as a result everything stopped working with an error which was not very specific. Thanks a lot!! (If you write it as an answer I can mark it as accepted ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was described as [Issue #190](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/issues/190) on the python-social-auth Github page. Please see this thread for possible workarounds.